# Question about casting char ** as (char *)

Tags: c

If I had the following piece of code, why and how does it work? Specifically, what is x (like what was created in the malloc line?) and why does the compiler allow me to cast a char ** to a (char *) with malloc.

```
char **x= (char *)malloc(1000);

*x="check\0";

printf("%s",x); //random bits in memory

printf("%c",x); //random bits in memory

x[0]='w';

x[1]='t';

x[2]='f';

x[3]='\0';

printf("%c",x); //random bits in memory

printf("%s",x); //w
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Hi , Welcome to stack overflow  .Please take the time to read to see [ASK]

Comment: Sorry, I made some edits to clarify what I am asking

Comment: If the compiler did not warn even once, it's time to throw it away and get a new one.

Comment: Undefined Behavior

Comment: This code is just nonsense. Try compiling it, to begin with. Then  `*x="check\0";` would for example point at a string literal instead of the malloced memory. Then you print various parts of a pointer with undefined behavior printf calls...

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't work.

If it is compiled with warnings, there's *lots* of warnings letting the user know.

The reason it can actually compile is that mostly the manipulation involves pointers. Pointers are just numbers, so it's possible to put a char** pointer into the space for a char*.  This doesn't help the program actually work of course.

The C Standard doesn't define these operations as errors, so the compiler lets them pass.

```
$ gcc -g -Wall  example.c -o example
m.c: In function ‘main’:
m.c:7:12: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  char **x= (char *)malloc(1000);
            ^
m.c:11:10: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char **’ [-Wformat=]
 printf("%s",x); //random bits in memory
         ~^
m.c:13:10: warning: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘char **’ [-Wformat=]
 printf("%c",x); //random bits in memory
         ~^
m.c:15:5: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
 x[0]='w';
     ^
m.c:17:5: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
 x[1]='t';
     ^
m.c:19:5: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
 x[2]='f';
     ^
m.c:23:10: warning: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘char **’ [-Wformat=]
 printf("%c",x); //random bits in memory
         ~^
m.c:25:10: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char **’ [-Wformat=]
 printf("%s",x); //w
```